# VB Script Join Function is throwing a type mismatch error

Tags: arrays, excel, vbscript, vba

I'm trying to fetch the data from an excel which contains a single query in each sheet.

so, here are my steps :

1) creating an excel application --> workbook --> worksheet objects

2) get all the sheet names and point to a specific sheet (which i'm doing harcoded for time being)

3) Retrieve all the rows from the sheet into an array of variants

4) finally join the each array variant into a single string

The final step i'm not able to achieve. when i'm using a for next loop i'm getting only 25 records into the string though the array has more than 25 elemets init or If I use join function for the array it's throwing a type mismatch error.

In my excel the query is always placed in multiple rows in first column itself.

To get the data into the array variable for the sheet names and actual query values i'm using a user defined push function. I want my arrays to grow dynamically based on the no. of the values.

please find my code below :

```
ReDim arrSheetNames(-1)

ReDim k(-1)

Dim strQry()


'create an excel application object
set myExcel =CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'create an excel workbook object
set myWorkBook=myExcel.WorkBooks.Open("D:\Test.xlsx")


'Get the sheetnames into an array
For i = 1 To myWorkBook.Sheets.Count
  fnPush arrSheetNames, myWorkBook.Sheets.Item(i).Name
Next


'Get th second sheet of the excel
set mysheet = myworkbook.Worksheets(arrSheetNames(0))


'Get the max row occupied in the excel file 
Row=mysheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Get the max column occupied in the excel file 
Col=mysheet.UsedRange.columns.count


'To read the data from the entire Excel file
For  i= 1 to Row
    For j=1 to Col
        fnPush k,mysheet.cells(i,j).value 
    Next
Next


m = join (arrSheetNames)
msgbox m


this is where im getting only 25 rows added to the string however there are 33 elements     in the array k.  

i=0
'
For i = 0 To UBound(k) Step 1
n = n & k(i)
Next

msgbox n 


when i'm using this statement it's throwing an error for type mismatch
strQry =  join(k)


msgbox strQry



'Save the Workbook
'myExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save

'Close the Workbook
myExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

'Close Excel
myExcel.Application.Quit

Set mysheet =nothing
Set myWorkBook = nothing
Set myExcel = nothing


 sub fnPush(arr, var) 
   dim uba 
   uba = UBound(arr) 
   redim preserve arr(uba+1) 
   arr(uba+1) = var 
 end sub
```

Comment: How long is the string with only 25 items?

Comment: Sorry..It looks like an issue with the MSGBOX limitation in displaying the characters. My string is receiving all the elements however the msgbox prompt limit is reaching for the 25th item in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MsgBox` function in VBScript can display a maximum of 1023 characters. I'm guessing you're reaching that limitation with your `join()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Dim strQry()` with `Dim strQry`, otherwise you should try to assign join result string to array that gives an error.